# Tooltip Hover for html.Button in Dash

Tags: python, dashboard

I'd like to add tooltips to some buttons in a Dash dashboard.

```
button = html.Button(
            key, 
            id={'type':'v_key', 'index':k_id}, 
            style={
                'class':'v_key',
                'width':'100%',
            }
)
```

Simple html buttons, dynamically generated. DCC doesn't seem to have its own button class.

How do I add a tooltips to them? Ideally with dynamically generated text from a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html buttons have a property called "title" that should be exactly what you are looking for. I would also recommend looking into the [Dash Bootstrap](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/) library as it has some additional components that make it easier to style your dashboard elements consistently.

Here is an example of a dbc.Button I have on my dashboard that I just added a title to:

```
dbc.Button(
    [html.I(className="fa-solid fa-download" )],
    id='exportConfBtn',
    title="Export",
    n_clicks=0,
    style={'margin-left':2},
    color='success'
)
```

[Export Button Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuxjY.png)

You should also be able to return text to this property dynamically with callbacks.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's embarrassingly simple. Thanks!